# Drupal 8 Configuration Entity translateable

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I was able to set up a Configuration Entity in Drupal 8. I was wondering if it was possible to flag that entity as translateable? I basically need the text in that configuration to map to all the languages we support in the site.